# Not able to update cloudformation stack when having AWS SNS:Topic Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cloudformation

I have create a cloudformation template that creates one SNS::Topic and bunch of other resources. Problem now is that when i try to update the stack, it fails with the following error

```
"Update to resource type AWS::SNS::Topic is not supported"
```

Stack Policy is:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*",
      "Condition" : {
        "StringEquals" : {
          "ResourceType" : ["AWS::SNS::Topic", "AWS::EC2::Subnet"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

CF Template is

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "......",
  "Resources": {
    "MySNSTopic":{
      "Type":"AWS::SNS::Topic",
      "Properties":{
        "DisplayName": "",
        "Subscription": [ ],
        "TopicName": { "Fn::Join": [ "-", [ "Simple", "sns", "topic" ] ] }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there anything (even hackable) that i can change to let aws complete the aws update stack without deleting/modifying sns_topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error message `Update to resource type AWS::SNS::Topic is not supported` is **not** complaining about your permissions, but about the limitations of CloudFormation templates for SNS Topics.

The [documentation for SNS resource templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#d0e65303) states the following:

> **Important**
>
> After you create an Amazon SNS topic, you cannot update its
>   properties by using AWS CloudFormation. You can modify an Amazon SNS
>   topic by using the AWS Management Console.

Instead, you might try adding a new topic, switching clients to use the new topic, then deleting the old topic.  If you are paranoid, you could do those in separate updates.

Comment: My problem is that i have not modified SNS topic portion. As such it should not complain about it.

Comment: What's changed in your template that you want to update?  Can you diff the template against an older version?

Answer (score 1):

This will also happen if you try to change topic subscriptions. If it is an option for you, just change topic's name in the template and it'll be recreated.