# Cannot update SNS topic using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-cloudformation

I have a **CloudFormation** template which invokes a **Lambda** function to create a **SNS** topic. The `create-stack` works fine and the stack is created and then the topic is created. However, when I try to use `update-stack` on the same template to update the topic, I see some errors.

[image]

I have no idea what this "Internal Failure" is. And the **CloudWatch** log does not show any error, the Lambda function is also returning response for the "update" request.

I found a guy asking the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330845/not-able-to-update-cloudformation-stack-when-having-aws-snstopic-resource) and the answer is

> Important
>
> After you create an Amazon SNS topic, you cannot update its properties
>   by using AWS CloudFormation. You can modify an Amazon SNS topic by
>   using the AWS Management Console.

As you know, my CloudFormation template is invoking a Lambda function to **create** the SNS topic. So, is it possible to call the CloudFormation template to invoke the Lambda function to **update** the SNS topic?  Any help is appreciated.

One more thing: **deleting** and then **creating** the SNS topic cannot be considered as a good solution because there are queues subscribing to this topic.

Comment: Does your Lambda function read the [RequestType](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requests.html#crpg-ref-request-fields) field of the request object received from CloudFormation?

Comment: @rbarni Yes. Everything in Lambda function is fine and the Lambda function is returning response for the "update" request.

Comment: Why are you calling a Lambda function to create the topic? Why not create it directly through CloudFormation? By the way, the quote that you provided is no longer shown on the referenced documentation page, so it probably isn't true anymore.

Comment: You will need to post source code to the lambda function underlying the `Custom::EnterpriseTopic` resource in your template, as the answer to your question seems to be depending entirely on the implementation of this resource.

Comment: Post the stack template as well, and the relevant properties you provide the template on `create` and on `update`.